# Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\Users\user\.thirdweb\creds\if-you-need-to-delete-this-open-an-issue-sync-disk-cache\thirdweb:cli'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mkdir, thirdweb

when I run npm run deploy it showing error like this:

```
Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\Users\user\.thirdweb\creds\if-you-need-to-delete-this-open-an-issue-sync-disk-cache\thirdweb:cli'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1396:3)
    at sync (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\86fd6f984ad48a35\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:74:13)
    at Cache.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\86fd6f984ad48a35\node_modules\sync-disk-cache\index.js:205:7)
    at obj.<computed> [as set] (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\86fd6f984ad48a35\node_modules\sync-disk-cache\index.js:51:19)
    at mp (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\86fd6f984ad48a35\node_modules\thirdweb\dist\cli\index.js:6:987)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Ye (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\86fd6f984ad48a35\node_modules\thirdweb\dist\cli\index.js:6:452)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\86fd6f984ad48a35\node_modules\thirdweb\dist\cli\index.js:434:3798)      
    at async Command.parseAsync (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\86fd6f984ad48a35\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:935:5)
    at async jm (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\86fd6f984ad48a35\node_modules\thirdweb\dist\cli\index.js:434:7324) {
  errno: -4071,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  code: 'EINVAL',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\user\\.thirdweb\\creds\\if-you-need-to-delete-this-open-an-issue-sync-disk-cache\\thirdweb:cli'
}
✔ Detected project type: hardhat
✖ Compilation failed
Error: Command failed: npx hardhat compile
ParserError: Expected ',' but got ':'
  --> contracts/CrowdFunding.sol:41:58:
   |
41 |         (bool sent,) = payable(campaign.owner).call(value:amount)("");
   |                                                          ^

Error HH600: Compilation failed
For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH600 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:419:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5) {
  code: 1,
  killed: false,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'npx hardhat compile'
}
```

Anyone, please help me to resolve this?
I am not able to deploy the smart contract into thirdweb.

Comment: Looks like thirdweb is trying to create an illegal dir. `:` is not allowed in Windows paths except as drive letter separator. File an issue with them on their issue tracker?